# Update statement using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Can anyone help me to implement the below logic in Hibernate?

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER 
SET balance  = (SELECT balance  FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Name='John')
WHERE NAME='Adam'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest one is to do direct SQL query:

```
session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE CUSTOMER"
                   + "  SET balance  = ("
                   + "     SELECT balance"
                   + "     FROM CUSTOMER"
                   + "     WHERE Name='John')"
                   + "  WHERE NAME='Adam'")
       .executeQuery();
```

Safier would be using object model.

```
Customer adam = session.createQuery("from Customer where name = :name").setParameter("name", "Adam").uniqueResult();
Customer john = session.createQuery("from Customer where name = :name").setParameter("name", "John").uniqueResult();
adam.setBalance(john.getBalance);
transaction.commit;
```